# Overloading member of python class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python class--it is a Linear Discriminant classifier...and so I have a train function and a query function in my class.

The query function takes a pandas dataframe as an input right now.  I'd like my class to be able to take a pandas dataframe with many samples...a numpy array or numpy matrix with many samples, and a single vector--either list or numpy array, where there will be minor differences in how I handle each.  But it is important that the function name stays the same (as versus `lda.query_with_dataframe`, `lda.query_with_matrix`, etc.)

The query function would classify each and return a dataframe.

So, in other languages, I would just "overload" the query function with other query functions that take different types.

Is there a way to do this in python, without doing some kind of manual type-checking dictionary hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this can be done with decorators, few different examples here [Decorator for overloading in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654666/decorator-for-overloading-in-python)

Comment: I'll check it out...Thanks man